Estimation of Maximal Functions
Assume that $f\in L_{\mathrm{loc}}^1\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right).$ Proof：if$f(x)=O(|x|^{-n})\left(|x|\right.\to\infty)$, then $Mf(x)=$
$$O(|x|^{-n}\log|x|)\:(|x|\to\infty).$$   I think we can use this answer Stein - maximal function and $L \log L$ spaces,  but i only get an integral type inequality estimation. how can i go on?
